# Turn on peristaltic pump relay for x amount of time using millis

Tags: c++, arduino, relay

This is my very first code in arduino. Im trying to build a simple watering automation for my garden. The code contain 3 main functions which is:

1. To topup fertilizer tank with water.
2. To add fertilizer into the water tank while water being topup with assumption fertilizer will be mix during this process.
3. To automated watering process through the day.

For the 1st and 3rd function, Im already got it done (theoretically + small scale system) i think. haha!

Now, for the fertilizer function number 2 (fertilizer_PUMP()), im using 2 peristaltic pump to add AB fertilizer solutions into the tank. Im trying to get the pump to run for the x amount of time but the the function only run once, after that the loop need to reset if both float switch become dry and wait for the bottom switch wet again. Could anyone please help and guide me which part im missing? Im open for any suggestion to improved my code too.. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

Im so sorry for the confusing. Actually for this function, below are my requirements.

1. If top float dry and bottom float wet > turn on both peristaltic pump for 10s(or more will change later) and stop.
2. Then, if top float dry and bottom float dry > reset.
3. Wait for next top float dry and bottom float wet.

Im really sorry again for the confusing. Kinda messed up with the logic previously.

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include "RTClib.h"
RTC_DS1307 RTC;

#define relayON HIGH
#define relayOFF LOW
#define floatWET HIGH
#define floatDRY LOW

const byte bottom_float = 13; //bottom position float switch
const byte top_float = 12; //top position float switch
const byte relay_topup_PUMP = 2; //Relay 1 for PUMP/Solenoid to topup water into the fertilizer tank
const byte relay_watering_PUMP = 3; //Relay 2 for scheduled watering PUMP
const byte relay_fertilizer_PUMPA = 4; //Relay 3 for Peristaltic PUMP "A" solution fertilizer
const byte relay_fertilizer_PUMPB = 5; //Relay 4 for Peristaltic PUMP "B" solution fertilizer

unsigned long previousMillis = 0;   // stores last time relay was active(on)
unsigned long fertilizer_pumpON_interval = 10000; //(10s for testing)Time to turn ON fertilizer peristaltic pump to get required EC reading
void topup_PUMP();
void watering_PUMP();
void fertilizer_PUMP();

void setup ()
{
  Serial.begin (9600);
  Wire.begin();
  //  RTC.begin();

  if (! RTC.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("Couldn't find RTC");
    while (1);
  }
  if (! RTC.isrunning())
  {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
  }
  // following line sets the RTC to the date & time this sketch was compiled
  // rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
  // This line sets the RTC with an explicit date & time, for example to set
  // January 21, 2014 at 3am you would call:
  // rtc.adjust(DateTime(2014, 1, 21, 3, 0, 0));

  pinMode (bottom_float, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode (top_float, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode (relay_topup_PUMP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (relay_watering_PUMP, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (relay_fertilizer_PUMPA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode (relay_fertilizer_PUMPB, OUTPUT);

  //digitalWrite (relay_topup_PUMP, relayOFF);
  //digitalWrite (relay_watering_PUMP, relayOFF);
  digitalWrite (relay_fertilizer_PUMPA, relayOFF);
  digitalWrite (relay_fertilizer_PUMPB, relayOFF);

  DateTime now = RTC.now();
}   // end of setup

void loop ()
{
  //  topup_PUMP();
  //  watering_PUMP();
  fertilizer_PUMP();
}

//void topup_PUMP()
//{
//  if (digitalRead (top_float) == floatDRY && digitalRead (bottom_float) == floatDRY)
//  {
//    Serial.println("TOPUP PUMP ON");
//    digitalWrite(relay_topup_PUMP, relayON);
//  }
//
//  if (digitalRead (top_float) == floatWET && digitalRead (bottom_float) == floatWET)
//  {
//    Serial.println("TOPUP PUMP OFF");
//    digitalWrite(relay_topup_PUMP, relayOFF);
//  }
//  delay (1000);
//}
//
//void watering_PUMP()
//{
////  DateTime now = RTC.now();
//      Serial.print(now.hour(), DEC);
//      Serial.print(':');
//      Serial.print(now.minute(), DEC);
//      Serial.print(':');
//      Serial.print(now.second(), DEC);
//      Serial.print(' ');
//      Serial.print(now.day(), DEC);
//      Serial.print('/');
//      Serial.print(now.month(), DEC);
//      Serial.print('/');
//      Serial.print(now.year(), DEC);
//      Serial.println();
//      delay(1000);
//
//  boolean watering_PUMPstate = false;
//  if (now.hour() == 15 && now.minute() >= 38 && now.minute() < 39) watering_PUMPstate = true;    //6:00 am - 5 mins
//  if (now.hour() == 15 && now.minute() >= 40 && now.minute() < 41) watering_PUMPstate = true;  //8:30 am - 5 mins
////  if (now.hour() == 11 && now.minute() >= 0 && now.minute() < 5) watering_PUMPstate = true;  //11:00 am - 5 mins
////  if (now.hour() == 13 && now.minute() >= 30 && now.minute() < 35) watering_PUMPstate = true;  //1:30 pm - 5 mins
////  if (now.hour() == 16 && now.minute() >= 0 && now.minute() < 10) watering_PUMPstate = true;  //4:00 pm - 10 mins
//
//  if (watering_PUMPstate == true)
//  {
//    digitalWrite(relay_watering_PUMP, relayON);
//    Serial.print("\t");
//    Serial.println(F("Watering Plant"));
//    Serial.print("\t");
//    Serial.println();
//  }
//  else
//  {
//    digitalWrite(relay_watering_PUMP, relayOFF);
//  }
//}

void fertilizer_PUMP()
{
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();
  boolean fertilizer_pumpON = false;
  if ((digitalRead (top_float) == floatDRY) && (digitalRead (bottom_float) == floatWET) && (currentTime - previousMillis <= fertilizer_pumpON_interval)) //Turn on for 10s
  {
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(currentTime);
    delay (1000);
    fertilizer_pumpON = true;
  }

  if (fertilizer_pumpON == true)
  {
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(F("Adding Fertilizer A and B"));
    delay (1000);
    digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPA, relayON);
    digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPB, relayON);

  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPA, relayOFF);
    digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPB, relayOFF);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define your currentTime and fertilizer_pumpON as global

```
unsigned long currentTime = 0;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;   // stores last time relay was active(on)
unsigned long fertilizer_pumpON_interval = 10000; //(10s for testing)Time to turn ON fertilizer peristaltic pump to get required EC reading
```

then in your

function void fertilizer_PUMP()

```
    if ((digitalRead (top_float) == floatDRY) 
        && (digitalRead (bottom_float) == floatWET) 
        && (currentTime - previousMillis <= fertilizer_pumpON_interval))
```

should include the state of the pump - I guess you only want to enter the if on pump off state

```
if ((digitalRead (top_float) == floatDRY)  // CAN BOTH STATES BE AT THE SAME TIME??
      && (digitalRead (bottom_float) == floatWET) 
      && (currentTime - previousMillis <= fertilizer_pumpON_interval))
```

I reduce to

```
 if((millis() - previousMillis > fertilizer_pumpON_interval) 
      && fertilizer_pumpON == true) {//time is up and state is on stop pump
      fertilizer_pumpON = false; // switch off
   }
  else if (PUMP_ON_condition == true && fertilizer_pumpON == false){ //check if we have to switch on
   fertilizer_pumpON = true; // switch on
    previousMillis  = millis(); // set timer to switch on time
   setRelaytoON = true; // Use YOUR COMMAND/PIN whatever you need
  }
  else {
 // DO NOTHING OR something while waiting or running use more ELSE IF if needed
  }
```

To sum it up

- Check for state AND time when running to stop
- Check for INIT command/conditions AND state set state & timer
- Check for emergency stop if needed
- do something/nothing if none of above applies

Break long clause up into single parts and check if states can have a different value at a time (logical error)

```
if (A == true && A == false)  // YOU CAN NEVER ENTER THIS CLAUSE
```

**EDIT** Implemented the logic as you described (read the comments in the code!) Add the line

```
bool fertilizer_pumpON = false;
```

before Setup() to the global vars and replace void fertilizer_PUMP()  with below code. A tip: Never use delay() - this blocks processing and renders time driven logics useless.

```
void fertilizer_PUMP() {
  // If top float dry and bottom float wet > turn on both peristaltic pump for 10s(or more will change later) and stop  CODE STARTS HERE
  if ((digitalRead (top_float) == floatDRY) && (digitalRead (bottom_float) == floatWET) &&  fertilizer_pumpON == false) {      //Turn on
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(millis());
    // delay (1000); // NEVER use delays or the whole logic wont work - delays BLOCK processing!
    fertilizer_pumpON = true;
    previousMillis = millis();
    Serial.print("\t");
    Serial.println(F("Adding Fertilizer A and B"));
    // delay (1000);
    digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPA, relayON);
    digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPB, relayON);
  }
  else if (fertilizer_pumpON == true && (millis() - previousMillis > fertilizer_pumpON_interval)) {    //Run for 10s then stop
    digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPA, relayOFF);
    digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPB, relayOFF);
    fertilizer_pumpON = false;
    Serial.println(F("Time elapsed"));
  }
  // If top float dry and bottom float wet > turn on both peristaltic pump for 10s(or more will change later) and stop  CODE STARTS HERE
  // Then, if top float dry and bottom float dry > reset.   CODE ENDS HERE
  else  if ((digitalRead (top_float) == floatDRY) && (digitalRead (bottom_float) == floatDRY && fertilizer_pumpON == true) ) {
    digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPA, relayOFF);
    digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPB, relayOFF);
    fertilizer_pumpON = false;
    Serial.println(F("Reset condition encountered"));
  }
  // Then, if top float dry and bottom float dry > reset.   CODE ENDS HERE
  else {  // Wait for next top float dry and bottom float wet. 
    Serial.println(F("Waiting ......"));  // use only for testing comment out afterwards
  } 
}
```

The code compiles so logic testing is up to you.

Comment: Dear @Codebreaker007 Thank your for your reply. For `if ((digitalRead (top_float) == floatDRY)  // CAN BOTH STATES BE AT THE SAME TIME??`, my idea to make sure that the water already start filling into the tank then only add fertilizer. I will test it after dinner..

Comment: As I said I do not know the logic so its up to you what to check, but make sure to work with states which are non blocking/preventing once the timer is started (except for emergency stops or like)

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little bit lost here. where should I declare this `PUMP_ON_condition == true`

Comment: PUMP_ON_condition is a dummy (=placeholder) for your condition when you turn on the pump - as I am not familiar with your code in detail It might be that: (digitalRead (top_float) == floatDRY) && (digitalRead (bottom_float) == floatWET) would replace PUMP_ON_condition == true

Comment: Im sorry for the confusing, could you please take a look on updated question? Im sorry again.

Comment: Thank you again, give me time to test the code and together with hardware. A bit busy today with my son's due to Movement Control Order.

Comment: Got it worked. Thank you so much for your help. One more question if I may ask, how can I check for fail safe condition like `fertilizer_pumpON` last turn on time. If the last ON more than X days, then, only turn on the fertilizer pump together with other condition if true. The water tank wont be finish so fast, maybe 4 or 5 day once need to topup water and fertilizer. Just want to avoid the fertilizer pump accidentally turn on and add fertilizer which will increase the EC reading.

Comment: You add a second state bool addFertilizer=true and a  timer with previousFertilizer = millis() when you add it and start it accordingly. Then you check it in the appropriate clause(s) and reset it after adding addFertilizer=false (be aware also my timers ar rollover safe you can only measure max 40 days on an Arduino. Please vote up and accept my answer.

Comment: Noted. I'll give it a try. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to change the way you are calling the function from loop:

Define global variable unsigned long previousMillis=-1; Then in void loop():

```
void loop()
{
  if((digitalRead (top_float) == floatDRY) && (digitalRead (bottom_float) == floatWET))
  { //If your above condition is correct(means you are read to pour fertilizer)
   if(previousMillis==-1)
    previousMillis=millis();//Set time elapsed till now in global variable
   if(previousMillis!=-1)
   {
    fertilizer_PUMP();//call function with a fixed previousMillis till millis()-previousMillis becomes 10s
   }
  }
}
```

Then in fertilizer_PUMP():

```
void fertilizer_PUMP()
{
 boolean fertilizer_pumpON = false;
 if (millis() - previousMillis <= fertilizer_pumpON_interval)) //Turn on for 10s
 {
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.println(currentTime);
  delay (1000);//This delay is not required because your effective interval would be 5 seconds then(10/2)
  //As you have a delay(1000) in the next if block too.
  fertilizer_pumpON = true;
 }
...
```

And in the same function:

```
else
   {
     digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPA, relayOFF);
     digitalWrite(relay_fertilizer_PUMPB, relayOFF);
     previousMillis=-1;//Wait for top float dry and bottom float wet, then set previousMillis
   }
```

Comment: No he needs more than one condition so please see my edited answer your solution wont work anyway test with 2 leds on your board before posting code

Comment: I'm really sorry not to have tried it on a board, due to its unavailability as we have lockdown here(but I did test it in tinkercad). But my logic was whenver the top is dry and bottom is wait,  we should enter the function with a fixed variable that holds time elapsed till that function call, and keep calling that function until millis()-fixed variable becomes 10 seconds as given by user. Anyways, I'll go into your edited answer! :)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Appreciate it!